# UiCollection View Flow layout in squilte ,Unexpected @ in the Program in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

As i updated my xcode project 6.3 to 7.0 and i used squilte database in that project, but there is error saying Unexpected @ in the program in above layer there is UiCollectionView Flow layout. Even it doesn't specify the exact position of error.[image]

Please Help i am confused. Thank You

Comment: Could you share the error you are having in UICollectionViewFlowLayout class?

Comment: There is no UICollectionViewFlowlayout.. That's why i m confused

Comment: Are you using Objective-c or Swift?

Comment: Please show us the class "UICollectionViewFlowLayout.h"